# Proving that limit exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

To show that limit exist and is equal to zero

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2y + xy^2)}{xy}$$

Comment: @Kristoffer thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
0\leq\left|\frac{\sin(xy(x+y))}{xy}\right|\leq|x+y|,
$$
because $|\sin x|\leq|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\\start\\by\\factoring\\xy $$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^2y+xy^2)}{xy}= \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y+xy^2}{xy} $$
$$
= \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy(x+y)}{xy} = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} x+y=0
$$